# Is the following thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, concurrency, locking

I have the following code and wonder whether it is thread safe. I only lock when I add or remove items from the collection but do not lock when I iterate over the collection. Locking while iterating would severely impact performance because the collection potentially contains hundreds of thousands of items. Any advice what to do to make this thread safe?

Thanks

```
public class Item
{
    public string DataPoint { get; private set; }

    public Item(string dataPoint)
    {
        DataPoint = dataPoint;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private List<Item> _items; 
    private readonly object myListLock = new object();

    public Test()
    {
        _items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public void Subscribe(Item item)
    {
        lock (myListLock)
        {
            if (!_items.Contains(item))
            {
                _items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(Item item)
    {
        lock (myListLock)
        {
            if (_items.Contains(item))
            {
                _items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Iterate()
    {
        foreach (var item in _items)
        {
            var dp = item.DataPoint;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I was curious and again profiled performance between an iteration that is not locked vs iterating inside the lock on the `myListLock` and the performance overhead of locking the iteration over 10 million items was actually quite minimal.

Comment: I know this may not be the comment you're looking for but have you though about a [Concurent Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is thread safe?

Comment: If you are modifying the collection you need to disable iteration because foreach trows a error if the collection got modified while it was iterating through it.

Comment: @Thomas, yes but it also heavily impacts performance in some tests I ran

Comment: In debug mode? Sometimes it's better to run secure and a bit slow than fast without seat belt... Don't you think ?

Comment: If you have very low lock contention ("very low" meaning "profile and see"), then concurrent collections will indeed behave slower. Also, iterating concurrent collections also acquires a full lock on all buckets and creates a separate list before iterating (similar to @xanatos' answer below) - this is not what dictionary is best suited for anyway. But this performance hit might be negligible compared to actual processing done inside `Iterate`.

Comment: Keep in mind that dictionary operations will use a default (`object`) comparer, so two `Item`s with equal `DataPoint` values will not be considered equal.

Comment: @Groo, thanks for pointing this out, I was aware of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't thread safe, because the collection could be modified while you look inside it... What you could do:

```
Item[] items; 

lock (myListLock)
{
    items = _items.ToArray();
}

foreach (var item in items)
{
    var dp = item.DataPoint;
}
```

so you duplicate the collection inside a `lock` before cycling on it. This clearly will use memory (because you have to duplicate the `List<>`) (`ConcurrentBag<>.GetEnumerator()` does nearly exactly this)

Note that this works only if `Item` is thread safe (for example because it is immutable)

Comment: Thank you, but why would `Item` need to be thread safe for this to work? If I changed the `DataPoint` property within `Item`  to `public set;` and changed `DataPoint` within the iteration why would this cause issues?

Comment: @Matt: Changing a string value won't cause an exception by itself, since changing a reference is an atomic value in .NET and strings are immutable. It depends on what you're doing inside the `Iterate` methods and whether this method expects that this value might change. I would recommend making the `Item` immutable also. If you need to change the `DataPoint` value, use your `Subscribe` and `Unsubscribe` methods (which are known to be thread safe) to replace the old immutable instance with a new one.

Comment: @MattWolf The example you gave perhaps isn't the complete working program you are using. If `DataPoint` is simply a `string` property that isn't calculated "on the fly" (so a property that doesn't have a complex `get`, but is, as you wrote, `get; set;`), then there isn't any problem. But if for example the `DataPoint` is calculated in the `get` based on other properties (like a `string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }` to give a simple example), then it could be not thread safe (because `FirstName` and `LastName` could be updated separately)

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for explaining. Just wondering, why did you not suggest to iterate within an additional lock? Is there a disadvantage in doing so?

Comment: @MattWolf Because it is exactly what you didn't want: *Locking while iterating would severely impact performance because the collection potentially contains hundreds of thousands of items*. You have to decide if iterating under lock is slower enough to merit duplicating the `List<>` before iterating on a copy of the `List<>` (clearly even duplicating under `lock` requires some time, and it is still a O(n) operation in time)

Comment: Fair, sorry. I actually performance profiled again just now and I do not know what I did wrong a while ago but the additional lock now even on 10 million items in the list hardly adds to the time it takes to iterate. The overhead is small enough to merit the lock rather than accepting the additional memory consumption by duplicating a potentially large list

Comment: @xanatos, last question if I may, thinking again about it, would the overhead not only be caused by the acquisition of the lock, hence one single time per calling `Iterate()`?

Comment: @MattWolf The overhead of a single `lock` is negligible (and is as you wrote, once per call to `Iterate`). I thought your problem was that while you are `Iterate()`ing, you don't want to block out other threads that want to `Subscribe`/`Unsubscribe`

Comment: @xanatos, no, sorry if I communicated confusingly. I just wanted to assure thread safety across all operations involving the list. Subscriptions/Unsubscriptions are very rare, and while the items in the list might be numerous the time it takes by blocking during iteration is acceptable enough.

Comment: @xanatos Nice answer but please don't forget to mention that in this case the access to the items of the list will be one-way; no edition inside the foreach loop will effect the original Item inventory.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. Note that all classes documented on MSDN has a section on Thread Safety (near the end): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The documentation for GetEnumerator has some more notes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The key point is that iteration is not itself thread-safe. Even if each individual iterated read from the collection is thread safe, a consistent iteration often breaks down if the collection is modified. You could get problems such as reading the same element twice or skipping some elements, even if the collection itself is never in an inconsistent state.

Btw, your Unsubscribe() is doing TWO linear searches of the list, which is probably not what you want. You shouldn't need to call Contains() before Remove().

Comment: I am aware but that does not answer my question. In your link it says that locking read and write operations would provide thread safety. I am unsure about iteration though...

Comment: @MattWolf Yes, I didn't read that MSDN section closely enough. I see you've already resolved the issue, but nonetheless I added some notes.

Answer (score 0):

In theory your code is not threadsafe.

---

In the background `foreach`performs a normal for loop and if you add an item from a distinct thread while `foreach`iterates through your list, an item might be left out. Also if you **remove** an item (from a distinct thread), you might get an AV exception or - even worse - gibberish data.

If you want your code to be threadsafe, you have two choices:

1. You can clone your list (I usually use the `.ToArray()` method for that purpose). It will lead to doubling the list in the memory with all its cost and the result might not be up-to-date for in-situ editions, or...
2. You can put your entire iteration in a locked block, which will result in blocking other threads accessing the array while you are performing a long-running operation.

Comment: @mg30rg, so if I iterate within a lock as well then it would be thread safe?

Comment: Because the above code is quite stable if used with care. I could write a long-running test code (without additional means of synchronisation) utilizing the code above which will not run on exceptions. That is why threading is hard.

Comment: @MattWolf Yes it would.

Comment: @mg30rg, thank you, if I may ask a closely related question. If I iterate within a lock and if the iteration itself was a longer-running process would this block access to other public, unrelated properties within the same class?

Comment: @MattWolf It would only block the execution of `lock()`-ed code.

Comment: This is not correct. You don't even need a separate thread to get an exception: simply add an item to the dictionary between two calls to `MoveNext` and you'll get an `InvalidOperationException`. There is nothing "stable" about OP's code. *if you add an item from a distinct thread while foreachiterates through your list, an item might be left out* - no, next call to `MoveNext` (implicitly done by `foreach`) will throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: @Groo And how exactly would you add an Item before the complete iteration finishes without a separate thread?

Comment: Example [one](https://ideone.com/u6goMx), example [two](https://ideone.com/8ja4uo).

Comment: @Groo I see now, where you went wrong. For starters, the code above uses a `List<>` not a dictionary. I have been using `List<>` for decades and **never** needed `.MoveNext()`. Also, your code(s) has nothing to do with thread safety. They are generically flowed and giving an example of an error that can not occur in the current scenario.

Comment: Then you should probably revisit your code, because [it fails for lists also](https://ideone.com/R4WYTx). Since `foreach` is [only syntactic sugar for `MoveNext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx), people don't have to use `MoveNext` explicitly - but that doesn't change the way it works. And the example demonstrates, in the simplest possible way, **what happens if you modify the list while enumerating it**. If this will make it easier, imagine that the `list.Add` is happening on a different thread (which is exactly what OP is asking).

Comment: @Groo I repeat, I have never used the sequential walkthrough of a list in my decade-long practice of C# coding, except for using foreach which positions the list-cursor to the first element and proceeds sequentially. Your code has the error of modifying the list (and not the elements) while iterating it. It is an error even if  you don't use threads. This is a no-go even when you use hacks. The asker does not do this. He _might_ create a situation when the additional thread does that and gets an AV **as I pointed out in my answer**, but in a well organized code it will almost never happen.

Comment: *"The asker does not do this."* So, OP's code is "thread safe", unless he actually uses a different thread to write to the list while iterating it? True, if you only use a single thread, no problems. But your answer seems to imply that he indeed might try to change it: *"In the background foreach performs a normal for loop and if you add an item from a distinct thread while foreach iterates through your list, an item might be left out."* - this is wrong, it will throw an exception while iterating, whenever a "distinct" thread tries to add an item.